# Exact and Heuristic Optimization Methods

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Could anyone give me a rough classification for which kind of nonlinear-  problems can I apply exact optimization methods (such as barrier function) and for which problems heuristic methods (such as population based methods)?

I read that heuristic methods are "better trial and error" methods?!
Thank you very much for your help!